# implicit conversion changes signedness 'int" to 'unsigned int"

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion, memset

I was using clang++ to compile the program and I need to compile it with no error in clang++. I got no error with other compilers.

The error line in the code is

```
memset(grid_, 0, sizeof(int) * x_quadrants * y_quadrants);
```

The whole function is like this:

```
Ocean::Ocean(int num_boats, int x_quadrants, int y_quadrants)
{
  grid_ = new int[x_quadrants * y_quadrants];
  memset(grid_, 0, sizeof(int) * x_quadrants * y_quadrants);
  x_quadrants_ = x_quadrants;
  y_quadrants_ = y_quadrants;
  boats_ = new Boat[num_boats];
  num_boats_ = num_boats;

  stats_.hits = 0;
  stats_.misses = 0;
  stats_.duplicates = 0;
  stats_.sunk = 0;
}
```

I am using memset so I won't get garbage value output when test with different driver. There's no need to provide command line for clang because I'm not allowed to change it.

Comment: What's the error? Where is the error? What are the types of the member variables of `Ocean` mentioned in the constructor? What do you mean when you say "no error with other compilers"? What were the compilation options there? What were the options with clang? Your question is missing a LOT of vital information.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Replace

```
grid_ = new int[x_quadrants * y_quadrants];
memset(grid_, 0, sizeof(int) * x_quadrants * y_quadrants);
```

with just

```
grid_ = new int[x_quadrants * y_quadrants]();
```

Note the parenthesis, that tells the compiler you want this zero-initialized (or really value-initialization, which reduces to zero-initialization here).

Even better, use a `std::vector` instead of this dangerous DIY scheme.

Comment: Thanks, the errors are now gone.  By the way, we actually haven't cover anything about STL yet. So I'm not sure how to use std::vector to get rid of this.

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof` returns a `std::size_t` which is unsigned. You're multiplying with (signed) `int` variables, hence the warning if you enable `-Wsign-conversion` in clang.

You can `static_cast` the dimensions to unsigned to avoid the warning - add a guard against negative values (`assert` for instance) if needed.

(Your code might benefit from using a [member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list).)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Perhaps I didn't make it clear, but in fact I am not allowed to get rid of the warning by changing the command line. But thanks.

Comment: I didn't tell you to change the command line at all, I told you how to fix the code to avoid the warning. (But Cheers's answer is much more appropriate in this case.)